# Mysql query to find a user with all of the given permissions

Tags: mysql

I want to find the users(userid) from a permissions table who have all of the given permissions. 
Something like :

select userid, permission from permissions where all_of permissions in ('view', 'delete', 'add', 'edit');

Note:
this query is not to do with mysql permissions. It is a generic question, assuming that I have a user_permissions table which has the following fields & data:

`userid | permission

1 | view

1 | add

2 | view

2 | delete

2 | add

2 | edit`


The query I'm asking should return

userid
2

Please let me know if this is not clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select userid, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT permissions ORDER BY permissions DESC) as permissions_grouped from permissions where permissions in ('view', 'delete', 'add', 'edit') GROUP BY userid HAVING permissions_grouped = "view,edit,delete,add";
```

thise will first get all the users who have any of those permissions, and then concat all of their permissions to an ordered string, then the having will only select rows with the right string.

edit: formatting

Comment: It worked. I never knew of group_concat. Thanks much for the prompt response.

Comment: group_concat is awesome, especially when combined with a HAVING clause. It lets you do things you used to think you needed sub-selects for :-)

Answer (score 1):

Look into the

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.user_privileges
WHERE grantee = '\'root\'@\'localhost\''
```

OR

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```

Comment: thanks for the response. this query is not to do with mysql permissions. It is a generic question, assuming that I have a user_permissions table which has the following fields & data:

userid | permission
1 | view
1 | add
2 | view
2 | delete
2 | add
2 | edit

The query I'm asking should return 

userid
2

Please let me know if this is not clear.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
    SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

Comment: But won't that just show all the current user's permissions, rather than all users who have a given permission?